# Python findall grabbing data within HTML tags using regular expression

Tags: python, html

Hi All/Python'ers/RegEx'ers,

I'm working lab exercise, learning Python RE package. 
I've got this data. I want to grab only the data between HTML tags. 
I tried this "[^(</?\w+>)]\d+" i.e. exclude all HTML tags TBODY or TD or /TD etc

It misses out first data 1850

```
<TBODY><TR><TD>1850</TD><TD>John</TD><TD>-0.339</TD><TD>-0.425</TD></TR></TBODY>
```

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/hu2TSo/1)

I'm trying

```
re.findall("[^(<\/?\w+>)]\d+", html_line)
```

Trying this `"(<\/?\w+>)"` grouping gets me all the HTML tags, I just to exclude ALL HTML tags, 
just opposite, so, I tried `[^(<\/?\w+>)]`

Thanks in Advance. N.
PS: Part of problem is, I shouldn't be using BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 1):

You should in general be using a package such as Beautiful Soup, which was designed to *parse* and handle HTML/XML content.  Using pure regex against HTML is not ideal, but you may try the following:

```
inp = "<TBODY><TR><TD>1850</TD><TD>-0.373</TD><TD>-0.339</TD><TD>-0.425</TD></TR></TBODY>"
matches = re.findall(r'<([^>]+)>(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)</\1>', inp)
print([i[1] for i in matches])
```

This prints:

```
['1850', '-0.373', '-0.339', '-0.425']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex used:

```
<([^>]+)>          match an opening HTML tag, and capture the tag label in \1
(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)  then match and capture a positive/negative number, with optional decimal
</\1>              match a closing HTML tag idential to what opened
```